# Feature Selection methods in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to do some text classification with SVMs in MATLAB and really would to know if MATLAB has any methods for feature selection(Chi Sq.,MI,....), For the reason that I wan to try various methods and keeping the best method, I don't have time to implement all of them. That's why I am looking for such methods in MATLAB.Does any one know?

Answer (score 3):

[`svmtrain`](http://www.mathworks.fr/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html)

MATLAB has other utilities for classification like [cluster analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/bq_679c.html), [random forests](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/br0gosr-1.html), etc.

If you don't have the required toolbox for `svmtrain`, I recommend [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). It's free and I've used it a lot with good results.

Answer (score 2):

The Statistics Toolbox has [sequentialfs](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/sequentialfs.html). See also the documentation on [feature selection](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/brj0qbu.html).

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach is [*dimensionality reduction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction). In MATLAB you can easily perform [PCA](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html) or [Factor analysis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/factoran.html).

Alternatively you can take a *wrapper approach to feature selection*. You would search through the space of features by taking a subset of features each time, and evaluating that subset using any classification algorithm you decide (LDA, Decision tree, SVM, ..). You can do this as an exhaustively or using some kind of heuristic to guide the search (greedy, GA, SA, ..)

If you have access to the *Bioinformatics Toolbox*, it has a [`randfeatures`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/randfeatures.html) function that does a similar thing. There's even a couple of [cool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/identifying-significant-features-and-classifying-protein-profiles.html) [demos](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/genetic-algorithm-search-for-features-in-mass-spectrometry-data.html) of actual use cases.

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help:

There are two ways of selecting the features in the classification:

1. Using fselect.py from libsvm tool directory (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#feature_selection_tool)
2. Using sequentialfs from statistics toolbox.

I would recommend using fselect.py as it provides more options - like automatic grid search for optimum parameters (using grid.py). It also provides an F-score based on the discrimination ability of the features (see http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/features.pdf for details of F-score).

Since fselect.py is written in python, either you can use python interface or as I prefer, use matlab to perform a system call to python:

```
system('python fselect.py <training file name>')
```

Its important that you have python installed, libsvm compiled (and you are in the tools directory of libsvm which has grid.py and other files).

It is necessary to have the training file in libsvm format (sparse format). You can do that by using sparse function in matlab and then libsvmwrite.

```
xtrain_sparse = sparse(xtrain)
libsvmwrite('filename.txt',ytrain,xtrain_sparse)
```

Hope this helps.

For sequentialfs with libsvm, you can see this post:

[Features selection with sequentialfs with libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469837/features-selection-with-sequentialfs-with-libsvm/23108755#23108755)