# How do you find the most discriminant terms in binary document classification?

Tags: document-classification, feature-selection

I want to use feature selection to find the terms in a document that are most useful for a binary classification task.

I've been looking around:
This mentions Mutual Information and the chi-squared test metric
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/feature-selection-1.html

MATLAB has a number of functions as well:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/brj0qbu.html
[Feature Selection in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419070/feature-selection-in-matalb) 
Of the above, relieff and rankfeatures look promising.

I do not know if my data follows a normal distribution. Any thoughts on which technique performs the best? Are there any newer methods you would suggest? The focus is to increase classification accuracy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is highly dependent on the nature of your data, I'd suggest playing with several options, possibly using a hold-out set for verification.
The easiest path would probably be to use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) or [RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/181/190/) for experimenting. Choosing from the plethora of options provided by them, you'll probably get acquainted with several other methods.

Having said that, I have found Mutual Information/Infogain to be useful on a large variety of problems.