# methods of lessening the number of features when machine learning on images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

I'm performing machine learning on a 25 x 125 image set. After getting  the rgb components it becomes 9375 features per example (and I have about 675). I was trying `fminunc` and `fminsearch` and I thought that there was something wrong with my method, because it was 'freezing', but when I decrease the number of features by a factor of 10, it took a while but worked. How can I minimise the number of features, while maintaining the information relevant in the picture? I tried k-means, but I don't see how that helps, as I still have the same number of features, just that there are a lot of redundancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for feature reduction or selection methods. For example see this library:
http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html
or see this question
[Feature Selection in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419070/feature-selection-in-matlab)
If you google `feature selection/reduction matlab` will find many relevant articles/tools.  Or you could google some commonly used methods like PCA (principal component analysis).

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll will have do some fiddling as I am still relatively new to matlab, but it seems like a great starting point!