# Features selection with sequentialfs with libsvm

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, libsvm

I want to use matlab toolbox to do feature selection. there is one good function there called sequentialfs that does a good job. However, I could not integrate it with LibSVM function to perform features selection. It works fine with KnnClassify, can somebody help me please. here is the code for KnnClassify:

fun1 = @(XT,yT,Xt,yt)...

```
    (sum((yt ~= knnclassify(Xt,XT,yT,5))));
```

[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun1,data,label,'cv',c,'options',opts,'direction','forward');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the libsvm functions to train and test an SVM on a particular featureset. I'd suggest writing things in a separate .m file (though in priciple I think it could go in an anonymous function). Something like:

```
function err = svmwrapper(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest)
  model = svmtrain(yTrain, xTrain, <svm parameters>);
  err = sum(svmpredict(yTest, xTest, model) ~= yTest);
end
```

and then you can call `sequentialfs` with:

```
[fs history] = sequentialfs(@svmwrapper, ...);
```

(You may need to check the order of the arguments to `svmtrain`, I can never remember which way round they should be).

The idea is that svmwrapper will train an SVM and return its error on the test set.

The anonymous equivalent would be:

```
svmwrapper = @(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest)sum(svmpredict(yTest, xTest, svmtrain(yTrain, xTrain, <svm parameters>) ~= yTest);
```

which doesn't look very nice.

Comment: Thanks man this is of a great help. This is what I wrote:
svmwrapper = @(TrainLbl, TrainData, TestLbl, TestData)sum(svmpredict(TestLbl, TestData, svmtrain(TrainLbl, TrainData, '-t 2 -c 8') ~= yTest));
[fs,history] = sequentialfs(svmwrapper,train_label,train_data_w,test_label,test_data_w,'options',opts,'direction','forward');

Comment: and I am getting this error:
Error using sequentialfs (line 196)
Data arguments X,Y,... must have the same numbers of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question is still open, but i got the function working using the following handle:

% The order of the inputs is important as svmpredict and svmtrain for libsvm take input as
% ytrain, xtrain but sequentialfs sends data as xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest

```
svfun = @(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest)sum(svmpredict(ytest,xtest,svmtrain(ytrain,xtrain,<svm options>)) ~= ytest);

[fs history] = sequentialfs(svfun,x,y)
```