# Data scaling algorithms in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, scaling

I'm new on data treatments and statistic so I have some question I don't know where to post, I hope this is the right place.

I'm currently working on a machine learning project. I have some data and I would like to use SVM. First of all I think that I need to apply scaling to put my data into a [0;1] interval. I applied this formula :

```
n = (e - e_min)/(e_max - e_min)
```

and then I applied mean normalization (element of the column - mean of this column) for each element of the column.

After that, I used SVM and I got good prediction results. But I would like to improve the results accuracy. So what can I do ? I think I can find a better scaling algorithm but I don't have any idea... Do you know scaling algorithm that could help me ? Or have any other idea to improve my prediction with SVM ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try different normalization methods. Common ones include the [L-norms, sometimes also called P-norms or simply linear norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)):

1. L-1 norm (Manhattan norm) divide by sum of column
2. L-2 norm (Euclidean norm) divide by euclidean length of column
3. L-infinity norm (Maximum norm) divide by maximum value of column

A more general method is called [feature selection or feature learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection). This attempts to identify which features are actually valuable to your classifier. [Feature Selection methods in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047940/feature-selection-methods-in-matlab) provides a few suggestions.

Another common thing to try is using different kernels for your SVM. The kernel transforms your features into a different feature space which may (or may not) make them more separable for your SVM. Matlab's [`svmtrain`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) function has several kernel options in the 'kernel_function' parameter. The documentation also provides a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-svm.html?searchHighlight=svm#bss0s6_-1) for using Gaussian kernels.

Improving a classifier's accuracy is usually a process of testing multiple combinations of normalization methods, feature selection methods, and kernels. Usually, you also test several different classifiers as well.

I would recommend comparing your results with an SVM to a Decision Forest or other non-linear method like AdaBoost. SVM's are very powerful for linearly separable data (or data that is linearly separable with a kernel), but if your data is not linearly separable playing with the norms and feature selection will only improve classification up to a point.